# vagrant, docker, shared volume not ready on initial provisioning

Tags: node.js, macos, docker, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm playing around with docker and vagrant to isolate my dev environment on os x. So far so good, i've found a couple of good tutorials and introductions but some of the posts seems to be outdated as vagrant envolved...

My main issue the mounting of a shared folder from my host machine to the docker container – it kind of works, but i have no idea if i'm running into a vagrant/docker issue or just doing something wrong.

Let me explain my current state:

I'm using the following `Vagrantfile.boot2docker` for my virtual machine and mount the current directory to `/app` in the vm. I can see the folder inside the vm and it's content changes, whenever I update the files on the host machine.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.3"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "yungsang/boot2docker"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/app", type: "rsync"
  # Uncomment below to use more than one instance at once
  # config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 2375, host: 2375, auto_correct: true
  # Fix busybox/udhcpc issue
  config.vm.provision :shell do |s|
    s.inline = <<-EOT
      if ! grep -qs ^nameserver /etc/resolv.conf; then
        sudo /sbin/udhcpc
      fi
      cat /etc/resolv.conf
    EOT
  end
  # Adjust datetime after suspend and resume
  config.vm.provision :shell do |s|
    s.inline = <<-EOT
      sudo /usr/local/bin/ntpclient -s -h pool.ntp.org
      date
    EOT
  end
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5000, host: 5000
end
```

In my `Vagrantfile` i'm creating two seperate docker containers, a isolated redis instance and my node app which mounts the app directory from the vm to the container `d.volumes=["/app:/foo"]`

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.define "redis" do |redis|
    redis.vm.provider 'docker' do |d|
      d.image  = 'redis:latest'
      #Comment the line below if you are running on a linux host
      d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "./Vagrantfile.boot2docker"
      d.name   = 'redis'
    end
  end
  config.vm.define "node_app" do |node_app|
      node_app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.name = 'node_app'
        d.build_dir = "."
        #Comment the line below if you are running on a linux host
        d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "./Vagrantfile.boot2docker"
        d.ports = ["5000:5000"]
        d.volumes = ["/app:/foo"]
        d.link('redis:redis')
      end
  end
end
```

My `Dockerfile` loads the latest nodejs container and copies the `package.json` and `app.js` from the host to the `app` directory before installing dependencies and running the app. The static copy of the folder from the current directory works well, my app connects to redis and works i can reach it as expected at http://192.168.33.10:5000 ! (Note: i've commented out the VOLUME command here, so files are just copied at container the beginning of the lifecylce)

```
FROM node:latest
#use vagrant shared folder
ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

# install your application's dependencies
RUN npm install
# exposes our app port
EXPOSE 5000
# replace this with your main "server" script file
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

After my first success i've tried to use my shared volume and changed the `Dockerfile` as follows:

```
FROM node:latest
#use vagrant shared folder
ADD . /foo
# mount volume
VOLUME ['/foo']
WORKDIR /foo

# install your application's dependencies
RUN npm install
# exposes our app port
EXPOSE 5000
# replace this with your main "server" script file
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

I've reloaded the vm and got a bunch of errors: mostly `no package.json found` or `npm module missing (express)`. I've figured  out – by using the first Dockerfile and the following node.js app https://gist.github.com/joernroeder/e86a3882360497c828f9 (which simply lists the files in `/foo` and there content) – that the volume needs some time to mount, replaces the content of `foo` with it's own initial content and removes the generated files (including the `node_modules` directory).
The files inside `/foo` therefore reflects the changes from the host, and syncing works well.

Do you have any tips and tricks for me how i can mount the volume in time, or are i'm doing something completly stupid here?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you take a look at docker-compose and docker-machine. They will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks!!! Building the setup with docker-machine with docker-compose solved my problems!

Answer (score 1):

The defined volume for the node_app container `d.volumes = ["/app:/foo"]` will be available only after the dockerfile is executed and the container is started.

A workaround is to first use `Add /app /foo` in the dockerfile and after container creation the static added data will be overriden by the volume mount.

An example implementaion with docker and compose can be found here: https://github.com/b00giZm/docker-compose-nodejs-examples/tree/master/02-express-redis-nodemon. Note that this is also possible without compose just using vagrant and docker providers.